# Express-hbs: Asynchronous Helper with options/attrs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working with [express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs) and Async Helpers but I need send options to the helper but async helpers doesn't support this feature ( or I don't know how ).
As you can see ( code below ) I'm trying to load a ADS helper/component but I need send extra information/attrs to render based on orientation a dimensions.

#### JavaScript

```
hbs.registerAsyncHelper( 'ads', function(filename, cb, options) {

       // options: is undefined

      // LOAD ADS FROM REMOVE SERVER.
       cb( new hbs.SafeString( ' == ADS  == ' ) );
});
```

#### HTML

```
{{{ads'page-x', 'vertical', '256x56' }}
```

Anybody can help me with this situation?
Thank you!

Comment: I think the correct handlebars HTML is {{{ads page-x vertical 256x56 }}. You don't need quotes or commas.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, you can currently (v0.7.10) only supply one parameter in express-hbs.

The only workaround I can think of is to use as JSON string as param and then use JSON.parse() to get them out again in your helper function. *This works only for static params.*

e.g.:

```
hbs.registerAsyncHelper( 'ads', function(arg, cb) {
    var options  = JSON.parse(arg);
    console.log(options);
    // LOAD ADS FROM REMOVE SERVER.
    cb( new hbs.SafeString( ' == ADS  == ' ) );
});
```

`{{{ads "[\"page-x\",\"vertical\",\"256x56\"]" }}}`

Reason for problem with multiple args in express-hbs following:

tl;dr

The express-hbs registerAsyncHelper code:

```
ExpressHbs.prototype.registerAsyncHelper = function(name, fn) {
    this.handlebars.registerHelper(name, function(context) {
        return async.resolve(fn.bind(this), context);
    });
};
```

only registers one parameter (context) with handlebars.registerHelper, but handlebars will call the registered helper with each supplied parameter as extra parameter. So the registered function should look like this:

```
ExpressHbs.prototype.registerAsyncHelper = function(name, fn) {
    this.handlebars.registerHelper(name, function(contextArgs) {
        return async.resolve(fn.bind(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(contextArgs));
    });
};
```

but that also requires a change of the resolve function. So you have to wait for a fix or fix it yourself, I guess.

Also as mentioned in the comment below your question the correct syntax for multiple arguments in handlebars is to not use a comma. So your template should like this (when handlebars-hbs is fixed):

`{{{ads 'page-x' 'vertical' '256x56'}}}`